# Is there any way to include all external js file in index.html with script tag

Tags: javascript, html, external-js

I want to include all .js files kept in some folder in index.html.
is there any way to import all .js files in one script tag.
just like we import all class in package with *

```
src
  Controller
  | HomeController.js
  | LoginController.js
  | AboutController.js
  Directive
  Services
  Views
index.html
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script src='Controller/*.js'>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

can we include all .js files with one script tag in index.html?

or

is there any other way to include these all js file dynamically ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use wildcard in src attribute of <script> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5028226/use-wildcard-in-src-attribute-of-script-tag)

Comment: You should minify all your js and css files and concatenate them into one file using a build tool e.g. NPM, Bower, Yarn, Grunt, or Gulp.